# How does one create a Stripe order with invoice?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I've got an api endpoint that listens to the `invoice.payment_succces` webhook event.  Whenever I get an invoice, I email a link to it to the user it is for.

This has worked so far for subscriptions, which automatically create an invoice, but does not appear to work the same for orders.

When ever I submit an order (like so)...

```
const order = await stripe.orders.create({
    customer: user.stripeCustomerId as string,
    currency: "usd",
    coupon: couponCode,
    items: [{
        type: "sku",
        parent: product.sku,
    }],
});
return stripe.orders.pay(order.id, {});
```

... the order is logged, and the payment occurs, but no invoice is ever generated.

How does one make stripe create an invoice when submitting an order?

Comment: Orders don't make use of Invoices, as per the discussion below. You may want to take a look at [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) which replaced the older, orders-based version, but now uses single payments or subscriptions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to send once-off invoices on a per-order basis, first configure your invoices

e.g.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('<test key>');

stripe.invoiceItems.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: 'usd',
  customer: 'cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a',
  description: 'Set-up fee',
});
```

Next you prepare a 'draft' invoice using `await.stripe.invoices.create`

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('<test key>');

(async () => {
  const invoice = await stripe.invoices.create({
    customer: 'cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a',
    billing: 'send_invoice',
    days_until_due: 30,
  });
})();
```

The draft invoice can be updated and when you are ready to bill, you can finalise it:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('<test key>');

stripe.invoices.sendInvoice(invoice.id, function(err, invoice) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

Source code taken from the [stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/sending)

If I've misunderstood the question, please comment. (It sounds like you are placing the order by the way your question is phrased... )

Hope this helps

Comment: I was trying to place an order, while still creating an invoice.  It appears that invoices are only for subscriptions or one-offs.

I'm pretty sure it's not possible currently.

Comment: @SephReed if you are the one that is placing an order, would what you need be an order confirmation / receipt (rather than an invoice)? An invoice is sent if payment is due, so if you've paid for it, a receipt would be in order. I'm not sure if receipt issuing in the API, I'm not familiar with all of it..

Comment: @SephReed check this out .. [Automatically send receipts when payments are successful](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts#automatically-send-receipts-when-payments-are-successful) Use await.stripe.charges.create..

Comment: Kind of.  In my case, we have a subscription kit, and there's a one off version of it as an order.  I'd like to be able to use the same webhook event and email template (which includes a link to an invoice) for both the order and the subscription.  Alas, it appears the two are so fundamentally different there is no overlap.

And I did see the receipts bit.  There's no api for it though.  It's not really a fully fledged feature.

Comment: @SephReed there is a [PaymentsIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/creating-payment-intents#creating-and-confirming) API? Maybe that's closer to what you are looking for..